# I'm trying to import file from my system but it is showing path directory error everytime

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, data-science, speech-to-text

I tried various ways to get the directory right. I'm Importing audio files which is stored on the desktop folder. I checked the list of directories it is showing desktop as a directory.

```
audio_path = 'Desktop\yes'
samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_path+"\yes.wav", sr = 16000)   #create samples of Audio file
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.set_title('Raw wave of ' + '../yes.wav')     #title 
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax1.plot(np.linspace(0, sample_rate/len(samples), sample_rate), samples)
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Raj Kumar Nayak\Desktop\yes\yes.wav'

Answer (score 0):

For Windows try this:

```
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop') 
audio_path = os.path.join(desktop,'yes')
```